# uninstall custom actions

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, uninstallation, custom-action

After which custom action should my C# custom actions execute? And what condition should I use so my custom action could run only on uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After which custom action should my C#
>   custom actions execute?

It depends on what they do.

> And what condition should I use so my
>   custom action could run only on
>   uninstall?

```
REMOVE = "ALL"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the condition in custom action call as to when they should be called.

Example :

```
<Custom Action="UpdateConfig" After="InstallFinalize">INSTALL_APPLICATION = "1"</Custom>
```

Here, as you can see the custom action UpdateConfig will be called after everything is installed and if Application was selected as feature while installing.